# Can Google Audit Reflection Pass

Tags: android, reflection

May I ask if reflection can be used for Bluetooth pairing in Google's app? Will Google Play review pass

Can Google's review reflection pass? I used the reflection method during the development of the app to adapt to the successful Bluetooth pairing of Huawei Hongmeng phones